# How to draw a line on frame from live video feed in opencv c++

Tags: c++, opencv, line

I want to draw a line on opencv frame in c++. For this I have below code where I am using `setMouseCallback(winName, onMouse, NULL);`. In below code I am using image:

```
Mat src;
const char* winName = "Image";
int start_x = 0;
int start_y = 0;
bool run_once = false;

void onMouse(int event, int x, int y, int f, void*) 
{

    if (cv::EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN)
    {
        if (f == 1)
        {
            if (run_once == false)
            {
                start_x = x;
                start_y = y;
                cout << "start x,y is : " << x << y << endl;
                run_once = true;

            }
        }
        if (f == 3)
        {
            cout << "start x,y is : " << start_x << start_y << endl;
            int end_x = x;
            int end_y = y;
            cout << "end x,y  is : " << end_x << end_y << endl;
            cv::line(src, cv::Point(start_x, start_y), cv::Point(end_x, end_y), Scalar(255), 2, 8, 0);
            imshow(winName, src);
            run_once = false;
        }


    }
}

int main()
{
    src = imread(<img path>, 1);

    namedWindow(winName, WINDOW_NORMAL);
    setMouseCallback(winName, onMouse, NULL);
    imshow(winName, src);
    while(1)
    {


    }

}
```

Using above code, if I left click using mouse on frame, it records `start_x start_y`. I drag my mouse to left/right and then right click and it records `end_x end_y` and simply draws a line and display it. This works fine but I want to achieve this functionality in live video frame.

The issue which I am facing in live video frame is that, in live video feed we are constantly displaying the frame in `while(1)` loop thus the line which is drawn is removed in next frame

```
void onMouse(int event, int x, int y, int f, void*)
{
   /*
    * SAME AS ABOVE
    */
}

int main(int, char**)
{
    VideoCapture cap(1); // open the default camera
    if (!cap.isOpened())  // check if we succeeded
        return -1;
    namedWindow(winName, WINDOW_NORMAL);
    setMouseCallback(winName, onMouse, NULL);


    for (;;)
    {

        cap >> src; // get a new frame from camera
        imshow(winName, src);
        if (waitKey(30) >= 0) break;
    }
    // the camera will be deinitialized automatically in VideoCapture destructor
    return 0;
}
```

In above code, we have `onMouse` function where we are using imshow to show the line drawn on frame but we also have `imshow` in `while(1)` loop thus the drawn line is not shown.

Is there anyway I can draw line on live video feed frame. Please help. Thanks

Comment: Instead of drawing directly on `src`, you can draw in another `Mat` object, for example `lines`, and then use `imshow(winName, src + lines)`. This way, `src` will change when switching to a new frame but `lines` stays the same

Comment: @Sunreef Can you give an example of it. I think I got it but need more refernece. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Sunreef suggested, you can create separate `cv::Mat` to keep picture with lines only and display `src` combined with this picture

```
// #0 NEW - add declaration of lines here so this Mat is visible in both onMouse and main scope
cv::Mat src, lines;

void onMouse(int event, int x, int y, int f, void*)
{        
    if (f == 3)
    {
        cout << "start x,y is : " << start_x << start_y << endl;
        int end_x = x;
        int end_y = y;
        cout << "end x,y  is : " << end_x << end_y << endl;

        // #1 NEW - draw line into lines instead of src
        cv::line(lines, cv::Point(start_x, start_y), cv::Point(end_x, end_y), Scalar(255), 2, 8, 0);

        // #2 NEW - remove unnecessary imshow here

        run_once = false;
     }
}

int main(int, char**)
{
    for (;;)
    {
        cap >> src; 

        // #3 NEW - init lines once, to be the same size, same type as src filled with zeros
        if(lines.empty()) lines = cv::Mat::zeros(src.size(), src.type());

        // #4 NEW - show lines combined with lines            
        imshow(winName, lines + src);

        if (waitKey(30) >= 0) break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This way only `lines` image is updated in `onMouse` (#1). No need to show it in `onMouse` event (#2) since it will be displayed anyway in the main loop (#4). But before you actualy display lines you overlay (add) them to the `src` image. The only tricky part is to initialize `lines` as soon as you know the size and type of `src` (#3). And remember to declare the `lines` first (#0) so that the image is visible globally, just like src.

I also suggest getting familiar with:

- [cv::add](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#add) - this is basically what `operator+` does
- [cv::Mat::type](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.3/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#af2d2652e552d7de635988f18a84b53e5)
- [cv::Mat::zeros](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.3/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#a095db10924bc801644a29074a755b6e9)
- [cv::Mat::empty](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.3/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#abbec3525a852e77998aba034813fded4)
- [cv::line](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d6/d6e/group__imgproc__draw.html#ga7078a9fae8c7e7d13d24dac2520ae4a2)